# Como ocultar partes de uma página com base em permissões de usuário usando asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

Estou com um projeto em mvc e estou utilizando o asp.net identity, tenho diferentes tipos de perfis, exemplo adm / tutoria / master / usuário e tenho áreas de acesso para cada perfil, além da view "home" que tem as urls que correspondem a cada perfil. Eu queria uma solução que usando o asp.net identity eu consigo ocultar determinadas urls na view "home" para que os outros perfils não vejam. Isso seria feito com uma implementação na hora que o usuario faz o login, daí ele ocultaria as url's que ele nao teria acesso, ou seja se um usuário comum fizer o login, só vai aparecer pra ele a url de usuário. Gostaria de saber se o asp.net identity tem alguma implementação própria para este tipo de controle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu arquivo cshtml você pode fazer condições para exibir os menus. Não conheço nada pronto para isso. Eu uso a solução abaixo:

Para exibir links para usuários logados(qualquer nível):

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
     <a href="#"> Minha Conta </a>
 }
```

Para exibir links de acordo com a Role do usuário

```
  @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  {
     <a href="#"> Criar novo usuário</a>
  }
```